# What is better, mapping a struct with 2 variables or having 2 mappings?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I have a mapping linking a key and a `byte32`, and I would like to extend it to store something as long as a byte64.

I chose to cut it in half, but what is the best (and lightest) way to store the two parts ? Should I map to a struct like this:

```
struct b64 {
    bytes32 part1;
    bytes32 part2;
}

mapping (uint256 => b64) public b64s;
```

Or use two mappings, like this:

```
mapping (uint256 => bytes32) public b64s_1;
mapping (uint256 => bytes32) public b64s_2;
```

I'm looking for the lightest solution. The only function making the mapping always writes both parts at the same time so I don't think there will be consistency issues with two mappings.

The first solution is cleaner but if I can save precious gas at every writing with the second one I'll take it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried both, and measured gas for both transactions. I got [107864 with a struct](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xbc2beb496dee3e0a4a3eb8022555b0e5e7128960adb06f75ac4e512203253e56), and [107856 with two mappings...](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0xf40972aa36ab3f8d876f77e211d50ca21e312ae26f6262c71ce03d89032aca6c). I'm pretty sure that the two bytes32 take all the gas, and the data structure are negligible in comparison.

So I'm using the cleaner one in my opinion, the struct.

Comment: This makes sense. Theoretically, these two methods should be identical, except that the double-mapping method would require 1 extra `sha3` per read or write, which is 30 gas, and the struct method would require a few extra `ADD`s and `POP`s, which would about balance it out